# Regular Expression for Extracting TV Station name from IPTV

Tags: regex

Im trying to extract the TV Station name from various TV Station formats used in IPTV M3U playlists. The types i have found:

> - NL| NPO 3 FHD HEVC
> - ||NL|| NPO 3 FHD HEVC
> - NL: NPO 3 FHD HEVC
> - NL: NPO 3 FHD+
> - NL: NPO 3 HD

Now im trying to extract the NPO 3, so i can match it against an external list with id's - to assign TV Guide. Im sure there are some other types - but i can't seem to get my regex right to work with all of them. The problem is that for dutch stations there is a NL but for other countries there are SE, PL, USA.

Ive come up this:

```
/^\|\||.*\||\|\||:|(.+) FHD+|FHD +|FHD|HD|4K|UHD/i
```

When using this string: NL| NPO 3 FHD HEVC it kind of works:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => NL|
            [1] =>  NPO 3 FHD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] =>  NPO 3
        )

)
1
```

When using this string: NL: NPO 3 FHD HEVC it results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => NL: NPO 3 FHD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => NL: NPO 3
        )

)
1
```

Im not very good with making regular expressions - and no matter what i try, i cant seem to get it to work with all kinds of formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract NPO 3 from those strings, you might use

```
^(?:[A-Z]+[|:]|\|\|[A-Z]+\|\|) (\S.*?) (?:FHD \+|FHD\+?|U?HD|4K)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z]+[|:]` Match 1+ occurrences of A-Z followed by either `|` or `:`
  - `|` Or
  - `\|\|[A-Z]+\|\|` Match `||` 1+ occurrences of A-~ and `||`
- `)` Close group
- `(\S.*?)`  Match a space, a non whitespace char and 0+ times any char
- `(?:FHD \+|FHD\+?|U?HD|4K)` Match one of the alternatives

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tWJvfd/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/tTNVQ)

Comment: Thank you very much! This does exactly what im looking for!

Comment: I extended your regex with [ ]? on the white space, so it also matches when there would be a NL:NPO 3 where there is no whitespace..